# Vue.js router on a shared hosting plan?

Tags: vue.js

I deployed a simple Vue.js website to a shared hosting plan. The website consists of a few internal links that use the router. Links such as `/contact` or `/about`.

I read that I need to use a `.htaccess` on shared web hosts so the router can navigate between its paths. Indeed, I added this code in the `.htaccess` file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

One thing I noticed is that the router can navigate between its internal links, for example if I'm on the [www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com) and click on the contact link, it goes to [www.domain.com/contact](http://www.domain.com/contact) and the page opens up.

However [www.domain.com/contact](http://www.domain.com/contact) doesn't exist in reality because if I type it out manually in the browser's address bar (without accessing it via a link on a page), then I get a page not found error. That sucks because Google probably won't be able to index my page then.

Is there any way to fix that?

The server is also running PHP. It has a PHP website on it beside the Vue.js one. I think I will need to touch the `.htacess` in the root folder instead of the one in Vue.js's dist folder.

The `.htaccess` in the root folder (the one in the root domain) looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Is there a way not to remove those? but also add the Vue.JS rules?

Comment: I'm not that familiar with apache config, but it looks fine to me. Are you sure your page is getting served by apache?

Comment: does [this](https://docs.netlify.com/routing/redirects/) help? I faced something similar after hosting vue app on netlify.

Comment: I updated my post.